# JavaScript Firebase Database web Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token with no reason

Tags: javascript, jquery, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

First of all i want to say that i searched a lot but i have not found the reason of my error.

I am working with firebase Database and i want to edit a specific child.
I do it in this way in my html page:

```
  firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
                      if (user) {
                      var uid = user.uid;

                    const databases = firebase.database().ref().child('Utenti').child(uid).set({
                            if($('#email').val().length > 8 ){
                            email: $('#email').val(), //email dal text input email ecc....
                            }
                            if($('#nome').val().length > 5 ){
                            named : $('#nome').val(), 
                            }
                    tipologia : 'Utente normale',
                    uid : user.uid
                    });


                };

        });
```

Now my `$('#email').val()` and my `$('#nome').val()` are the result of two different input area. So, once i click a button i call the event listener and i perform the action to edit the data in my specified node.

But i get the error "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token (" and the line is `if($('#email').val().length > 8 ){` and obiuously the next one is `if($('#nome').val().length > 5 ){`.
What happened?
What is wrong with this code? Please do not mark as duplicated!

Comment: You can't use an `if` statement in the declaration of an object (`{}`). Create the object beforehand, and then pass it in the `.set()` function of firebase.
It may be good to mention: I couldn't see the error in your code very quickly, because it's a mess.. Try your best to keep your code nice and readable, and you won't have as many problems in the future.

Comment: @JeffHuijsmans if you write that into an answer with a sample of how to do it, that would allow us to quickly get this question resolved.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen on it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this

```
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
                      if (user) {
                      var uid = user.uid;
                    var obj={};
                    if($('#email').val().length > 8 ){
                        obj["email"]=$('#email').val();
                    }
                    if($('#nome').val().length > 5 ){
                        obj["named"]=$('#nome').val();
                    }
                    obj["tipologia"]='Utente normale';
                    obj["uid"]=user.uid;
        const databases = firebase.database().ref().child('Utenti').child(uid).set(obj);
                      }
        })
```

Create an  object & Then pass it to set method.

Comment: i get this error: Firebase.set failed: First argument contains undefined in property . What does it mean?

Comment: is user.uid underfined ?

Comment: put a debug & check which value goes undefined in obj.
As per rule
Value in firebase can be anything but not undefined. it can be null.
So you will have to write code to keep it null when it is undefined. tell mw which thing goes undefined in obj.

Comment: just found a fix. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Alfred try to keep your code indented properly and clean, that way it's easier for yourself to find out a bug!

Comment: @Alfred glad to help :)

Answer (score 1):

You can't use an `if` statement in the declaration of an object (`{}`). Create the object beforehand, and then pass it in the `.set()` function of firebase.

Example:

```
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
    if (user) {
        var uid = user.uid;

        var setObj = {
            tipologia: 'Utente normale',
            uid: user.uid
        };

        if($('#email').val().length > 8 ) setObj.email = $('#email').val();
        if($('#nome').val().length > 5 ) setObj.named = $('#nome').val();

        const databases = firebase.database().ref().child('Utenti').child(uid).set(setObj);
    };
});
```